# What function yields a hat matrix with the smallest Frobenius norm to a given hat matrix?

Tags: regression, linear-model, matrix, projection

**Phrasing Attempt 1**

If I have one function $f_1: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{D_1}$ that yields a particular [hat matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix) $P_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$, how do I find the function $f_2: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{D_2}$ that yields a hat matrix $P_2$ with the smallest Frobenius norm to $P_1$?

**Phrasing Attempt 2**

I'm encountering the following problem in my research and I'm curious to know what tools people have discovered to solve the following problem.

Let $f_1: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{D_1}$ and let $f_2: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{D_2}$ be two functions and let the following be a supervised dataset for linear regression:

$$\big\{(x_n, y_n) \big \}_{n=1}^N$$

Assuming linear models, $\hat{y}_1 := W_1 f_1(x)$ and $\hat{y}_2 := W_2 f_2(x)$, the [hat matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix) are given by:

$$P_1 := F_1 (F_1^T F_1)^{-1} F_1^T \quad \quad \text{and} \quad \quad P_2 :L= F_2 (F_2^T F_2)^{-1} F_2^T $$

where $F_1$ is the $\mathbb{R}^{N \times D_1}$ matrix formed by applying $f_1$ to each $x_n$ and $F_2$ is the $\mathbb{R}^{N \times D_2}$ matrix formed similarly. Both hat matrices are in $\mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$. How do I solve the following optimization problem?

$$\arg \min_{f_2} || P_1 - P_2||_F^2$$

Comment: To clarify, you are applying $f_i$ to each row of your data matrix $X$, where each row is a $d$-dimensional vector $x$, to produce a new matrix $F_i$, where each row is a $D_i$-dimensional vector $z$, such that $d \neq D_i$, right?

Comment: Thanks for asking! I don't want to make an assumption regarding the relative dimensions. $d \neq D_i$ is permissible, but I don't want to rule out that $d = D_i$

Comment: But your comment about applying $f_i$ to each row of the data matrix $X$ to produce a new matrix $F_i$ is correct

Comment: If we assume that $P_1$ is a given matrix (not necessarily the result of $f_1$), and if we assume that $f_2$ is linear (a matrix) and must be orthogonal, the problem reduces to the [orthogonal Procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem). I think making the problem easier (constraining $f_1$ and $f_2$ to be linear) and then generalizing later *may* be helpful.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I don't want to assume that $f_2$ is linear or orthogonal